# Segfaults on appending char* arrays

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm making a lexical analyzer and this is a function out of the whole thing. This function takes as argument a char, c, and appends this char to the end of an already defined char* array (yytext). It then increments the length of the text (yylen).

I keep getting segfaults on the shown line when it enters this function. What am I doing wrong here? Thanks.

BTW: can't use the strncpy/strcat, etc. (although if you want you can show me that implementation too)

This is my code:

```
extern char *yytext;
extern int *yylen;

void consume(char c){
    int s = *yylen + 1;                  //gets yylen (length of yytext) and adds 1
                                         //now seg faults here
    char* newArray = new char[s];
    for (int i = 0;i < s - 1;i++){
        newArray[i] = yytext[i];             //copy all chars from existing yytext into newArray
    }
    newArray[s-1] = c;                       //append c to the end of newArray
    for (int i = 0;i < s;i++){               //copy all chars + c back to yytext
        yytext[i] = newArray[i];
    }
    yylen++;
}
```

Comment: Updated code: now segfaults on different line.

Comment: Is `yylen` pointing to a valid memory location that has a valid value ?

Answer (score 1):

You have

```
extern int *yylen;
```

but try to use it like so:

```
int s = (int)yylen + 1;
```

If the variable is an `int *`, use it like an `int *` and dereference to get the `int`. If it is supposed to be an `int`, then declare it as such.

Comment: so I could change it to
    extern int yylen;

or
int s = (int)*yylen + 1;

Comment: Yes, depending on how that variable is used in other parts of the program. (You don't need to case in the latter case, btw)

Comment: er, you don't need to *cast*

Answer (score 0):

That can t work:

```
int s = (int)yylen + 1;                  //gets yylen (length of yytext) and adds 1
char newArray[s];
```

use malloc or a big enought buffer

```
char * newarray=(char*)(malloc(s));
```

Comment: What about using char* newArray = new char[s];

Comment: yep c++ sorry. I just changed that.

Answer (score 0):

Every C-style string should be null-terminated. From your description it seems you need to append the character at `c`. So, you need 2 extra locations ( one is for appending the character and other for null-terminator ).

Next, `yylen` is of type `int *`. You need to dereference it to get the length (assuming it is pointing to valid memory location ). So, try -

```
int s = *yylen + 2;
```

I don't see the need of temporary array but there might be a reason why you are doing it. Now,

```
yytext[i] = newArray[i];             //seg faults here
```

you have to check if `yytext` is pointing to a valid **write** memory location. If yes, then is it long enough to fill the appending character plus null terminator.

But I would recommend using `std::string` than working with character arrays. Using it would be a one liner to solve the problem.